# How to get Maven dependencies printed to a file in a readable format?

Tags: maven, build-dependencies

I am working on a big projects with many pom.xml files and I need to specify all the libraries that I use. This means that I need to read pom.xml files recursively and get groupId, artifactId, scope and version. I checked out mvn dependency:tree but I can't find a way to print it to a file in a readable format. I saw appendOutput but I saw no example on how to use it in cmd. I saw some solutions done in Linux but I only have access to Windows XP.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

This can (at least now) be done with command line options to the dependency:tree plugin.

Try:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Doutput=/path/to/file
```

Reference: [Maven Dependency Plugin Page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html#dependency:tree)

You only asked about "readable" format, but you can also pass the -DoutputType parameter with various options.  Also note that the version I have installed, I get the following warning:

```
[WARNING] The parameter output is deprecated. Use outputFile instead.
```

So, consider trying it with -DoutputFile=/path/to/file

Also, I was unable to get the -DoutputType paramater to give me anything other than the default text, but didn't have a chance to play around with it. YMMV.

Comment: -Dmdep.outputFile=/path/to/file.txt worked, all the other options didn't

Comment: As of Maven 3.5.0 and maven-dependency-plugin 2.8, `-DoutputFile=/path/to/file.txt` works with no warning.

Comment: `mvn dependency:tree` does not print transitive dependencies through the parent pom, making this unappropriate for debugging purposes

Comment: refs: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html#outputFile

Answer (score 19):

If you have multiple modules under the same repo/project and want the dependencies of all the modules in one file, so as to be able to diff b/w one build and another to see if something changed somewhere, you can do

```
$project_dir> mvn dependency:tree -DoutputFile=<absolute_path_to_file> -DappendOutput=true
```

e.g.

```
$project_dir> mvn dependency:tree -DoutputFile=`pwd`/mvn_dependency_tree.txt -DappendOutput=true
```

See other options available at https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html

Comment: passing relative path also works

Answer (score 10):

Adding the

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.tooling</groupId>
    <artifactId>depends-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

plugin produces a `classes/META-INF/maven/dependencies.properties` file with the project dependencies easily parseable.

Example of the output produced:

```
# Project dependencies generated by the Apache ServiceMix Maven Plugin
# Generated at: Mon Oct 10 17:43:00 CEST 2011

groupId = my.group.name
artifactId = my.artifact.name
version = 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
my.group.name/my.artifact.name/version = 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

# dependencies

junit/junit/version = 4.8
junit/junit/type = jar
junit/junit/scope = test

org.easymock/easymock/version = 2.4
org.easymock/easymock/type = jar
org.easymock/easymock/scope = test
```

Answer (score 5):

On GNU/Linux I would just do `mvn dependency:tree > myFile`. However, if you're restricted to Windows only, than I would look for Windows' syntax for streaming the output of a command.

According to [this site](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) (just a top-results from Google) it seems that Windows' console also use `>` sign to direct the output stream to i.e. a file. 
So would you mind trying this?

Answer (score 2):

I have run the below command and got the file having all the maven dependency.

```
mvn dependency:tree -DoutputFile=temp/mvn_dependency_tree.txt
```

This command will create a folder named "temp" and inside this folder a file name mvn_dependency_tree.txt will be created with all the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can always install [MinGW and MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/) and then use the Linux examples using `dependency:tree` in Windows

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [effective-pom](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html) (in conjunction with some linux commands for saving the file) can be sufficient for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html#outputFile

If the project has multi modules and you want to output the dependency to a single file, use absolute path and append options.

mvn dependency:tree -DoutputFile=/abs_path/deps.txt -DappendOutput=true