# Maven: dependency:tree gives wrong results if outputType is graph and project contains multiple modules

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

My project structure looks like this:

1. PARENT POM which holds external dependencies [located separately from the project]
2. MAIN POM, which is a child of PARENT POM, it holds a set of child modules [it is located in root folder of the project]
3. CHILD MODULES, each of them is a child of MAIN POM, [a set of folders inside the root folder]

I want to create a dependency graph of my project. For this I want to print the dependency data with

```
 mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:tree
```

-DoutputFile=deps.tgf -DoutputType=tgf -DappendOutput=true

and then open generated file with some editor.

The problem is that my approach works as expected only for simple projects, formed by one POM. For my case it fails.

simple

> mvn dependency:tree

works as expected and shows all the dependencies, including the child modules. But when I try to create my dependency tree with **`outputFile=text`** parameter, as I have written above, - it fails. It fetches only the dependencies of the Pom, on which I run the command, i.e. MAIN POM in my case. The child modules are missing!

Is there a way to fix it? 
Indeed, it looks like a bug in Maven: `mvn dependency:tree` works OK, and `mvn dependency:tree -DoutputFile=text` produces logically wrong results.

UPDATE

I have found what happens. It just stores the dependencies file in the child projects! I.e. if I have `childProject` which is a module inside MAIN POM - Maven create `outputFile.txt` inside this project! And it does not aggregate the files. Not sure I can do something with this apart from writing a script.

Comment: does this not work mvn dependency:tree > tree.txt?

Comment: it works. but in fact I need outputType=tgf to produce a scheme of dependencies.

Comment: @MiamiBeach were you ever able to find the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found solution in [How to get Maven dependencies printed to a file in a readable format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953888/how-to-get-maven-dependencies-printed-to-a-file-in-a-readable-format)

just add -DappendOutput=true

like this

```
 mvn dependency:tree -Doutput=/path/to/file -DappendOutput=true
```